# Функция strlen() в php врёт

Tags: php, strlen

`strlen('Круто');` - показывает, что символов 6. На самом деле их 5. `strlen('Круто! Мне очень нравится! :)');` - показывает, что символов 50. На самом деле их 29.

Как так?

Comment: > strlen('Круто'); - показывает, что символов 6

Вообще, это странно. 10 — понимаю, 5 — понимаю, даже 16 могу представить, но 6 у меня никак не получается...

Comment: @drdaeman, а так - strlen('Kpyтo'); ? В utf-8 выдаст 6... ;)

Comment: Вон оно как!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[mb_strlen](http://www.php.su/functions/?mb-strlen)

> mb_strlen() возвращает количество символов в строке str, имеющих кодировку символов encoding. Многобайтный символ вычисляется как 1.

Comment: @thunder, да, спасибо. Это и использовал. Догадался спустя 5 минут. Вопрос удалил, но он не удалился. Странно... :)

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что чтобы в таких строках сделать выбор подстроки, проще всего разделить строку на массив (explode вроде в пхп это делает), выбрать количество элементов, а затем склетить с помощью implode.